# socket.io connect role authentication

Tags: node.js, express, socket.io

I was thinking to implement a role/auth model on top of socket.io connections. There is a lot out there about this, especially for token authentication. But what about what I am attaching below? What would be wrong with this approach?

The idea with the code below is to give access to socket.io connections only to specific roles.

```
var role = true;

module.exports = function (io) {

  if (role == true){
    'use strict';
    io.on('connection', function (socket) {
      socket.on('chat message', function(msg){
      io.emit('chat message', msg);
    });
   });
  };
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Passport.socketio](https://github.com/jfromaniello/passport.socketio) to authentify your socket connections. It works really well with express. Here is a sample app :

```
var express = require('express');
var passport = require('passport');
var passportSocketIo = require("passport.socketio");
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var session      = require('express-session');
var app = express();
var RedisStore = require('connect-redis')(session);
var sessionStore = new RedisStore({
  host: 'localhost',
  port: 6379,
  db: 2,
});

app.use(session({
  store: sessionStore,
  secret: 'YOUR_SECRET_HERE'
}));

app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());


var io = require('socket.io').listen(http.createServer(app).listen(app.get('port'), function(){
    console.log('Express server listening on port ' + app.get('port'));
}));

io.use(passportSocketIo.authorize({
  cookieParser: cookieParser,
  secret:      'YOUR_SECRET_HERE',
  store:       sessionStore,
}));
```

In your case, you'd have to add the roles to your passport users. The user info can then be accessed in *socket.request.user*

```
io.sockets.on('connection', function(socket) {
  var user = socket.request.user;
  if (user.role == true){
    //do something
  }
});
```

Please note that you have to use a sessionStore, local storage doesn't work with passport. Refer to the Git page above for different possibilities.